# update using modal of bootstrap in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem when updating the password of student, I am using the modal of bootstrap: -> here is the picture [updatepassword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVo85.png)

here is my modal and the action is studentpasswordupdate/updatepasswordstudent, I retrieve the value using echo $Password in session

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Change Password</h4>
        </div>
          <div class="modal-body"><br>
       
           <form  action="<?php echo site_url("studentpasswordupdate/updatepasswordstudent") ?>" method="POST">
         
               <div class="l">
                   <label class=" input-lg" style="font-size: 28px;">Password:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input  class="k" type="text" name="Password" value="<?php echo $Password ?>" >                        
         
               </div>
               <br> <br><br>
  
    <div class="modal-footer">    
    <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-info m" >Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
                       </form>
   
        
        
   
   
  
        </div>
       
         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is my controller/method:

```html
class Studentpasswordupdate extends CI_Controller {
    //put your code here
    function updatepasswordstudent(){
       
       $id = $this->input->post('Id');
            
          $data= array(
            'Password' => $this->input->post('Password')
                 ); 
           
            $this->db->where('Id', $id);
            $this->db->update('studentinformation',$data);
            $hasError = $this->db->_error_message();
            
            echo $hasError;
          redirect('studentform/index', 'refresh');
        }
    

}
```

Comment: what is the error?? and there in no field call id in view

Comment: nothing error when I click save and it will redirect in student details form

Comment: comment all controller code and `echo $this->input->post('Id');` and post output

Comment: I will put the $id in method parameter?

Comment: inside this `updatepasswordstudent` function add that and post showme output

Comment: I used only session to retrieve like this     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Id ?>">

Comment: this is show when I put $id in method parameter     ------>                         A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Studentpasswordupdate::updatepasswordstudent()

Filename: controllers/studentpasswordupdate.php

Line Number: 16

Comment: chck my answer below

Comment: sorry but still nothing happen when updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class Studentpasswordupdate extends CI_Controller {

    function updatepasswordstudent()
    {

        $id = $this->input->post('Id');        
        $data = array(
                'Password' => $this->input->post('Password')
            ); 
        $this->db->where('Id', $id);

        if (!$this->db->update('studentinformation',$data)) 
        {
            $hasError = $this->db->_error_message();

            echo $hasError;
        }
        else{
            redirect('studentform/index', 'refresh');
        }
    } 
}
```

**In View**

Set name field  foe this

```
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?php echo $Id ?>">
```

Comment: is your table have field call `Password` as same as you add on here ??

Comment: So there is no error with it. All working fine. Add all codes as i mentioned and test once

Comment: wait wait wait wait, sorry it already save, it will not view directly or even refresh the screen, it need logout thank you sir

Comment: sorry my bad, so it need completely logout in order to view the update even i refresh the page sorry